# vbs Exclude CLOB data while exporting recordset

Tags: vbscript

I am trying to export a recordset to excel in vbs, but its erroring out unable to download CLOB data. Could someone help me how to export a recordset to excel in vbs excluding any CLOB data in the recorset.

When in manually export to excel dataset in Toad, i have the options to exclude CLOB, but I am unable to figure out how to do so programatically in vbs.

Comment: Show your code as well as the exact error message.

Comment: If you don't need the clob fields from database, don't include them in your query.